# Unable to click on toggle dropdown button to be able to get to logout

Tags: java, selenium

I should double click on user toggle drop down to be able to expand drop down and get log out button.

I tried different approach:

```
wait=new WebDriverWait(wd, 10); 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("dropdown-toggle")));

Actions act = new Actions(wd);
act.moveToElement(wd.findElement(By.className("dropdown-toggle"))).doubleClick().build().perform();
```

The drop down toggle isn't getting expanded at all.

Toggle drop down

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that your actually finding the web element.

Second, make sure that element is not in a different frame/iframe. If so you will have to switch to that frame in order to find or interact with the element.

Third, you may have to move to the element first. The double click action may only work if the element is under the mouse pointer.

Comment: Thank you for response, Mike. I was able to locate identical element correctly. When try to move to the element and perform double click on drop down toggle it is not expanded for me as it it hapenning when i do it manually.

Comment: It is just highlights with red color but not opening dropdown

Answer (score 0):

As its working with debugging mode, Instead of using build() method, try with click() method,

```
Actions act = new Actions(wd);
act.moveToElement(wd.findElement(By.className("dropdown-toggle"))).doubleClick().click().perform();
```

OR you can operate with `JavaScript` functionality,

```
WebElement findName=wd.findElement(By.className("dropdown-toggle")); 
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", findName);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is worked out for me when I run first time but then fail again!

Comment: Yes, you are right, it is working in debugging mode but doesn't work when i run it

Comment: After that I wait for logout button                                                      wait = new WebDriverWait(wd, 30);
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("#aLogout"))).click();

Comment: I am trying to figure it out why it is working in debug mode but does not work when I run script.

Comment: @YM1 , I have added one more provision to fetch Button click with the use of Javascript functionality.